# Como criar um método de pesquisa por elementos em uma ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

Supondo uma ArrayList que armazene objetos, e esses objetos possuem atributos de diversos tipos (int, String , float,etc...). Sabendo disso eu quero criar um método para achar um objeto na ArrayList através de uma palavra chave ou numero que pode está dentro de um elemento da Array ou não. Sem ser pelo index de cada elemento.

Comment: Seja mais especifico no que está a tentar fazer. Dê um exemplo dos objetos que tem e do tipo de procura que pretende fazer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer algo como:

```
public class Pessoa {

    private int id;
    private String nome;
    private int idade;

    public Pessoa(int id, String nome, int idade) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.idade = idade;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public int getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }

    public void setIdade(int idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Pessoa> pessoas = new ArrayList<Pessoa>();

        pessoas.add(new Pessoa(1, "José", 32));
        pessoas.add(new Pessoa(2, "João", 25));
        pessoas.add(new Pessoa(3, "Maria", 43));

        Pessoa pessoaPeloNome = buscaPeloNome(pessoas, "João");
        Pessoa pessoaPelaIdade = buscaPelaIdade(pessoas, 43);

        if(pessoaPeloNome != null) {
            System.out.println("Pessoa pelo nome: " + pessoaPeloNome.getId() + " | " + pessoaPeloNome.getNome() + " | " + pessoaPeloNome.getIdade());
        }

        if(pessoaPelaIdade != null) {
            System.out.println("Pessoa pela idade: " + pessoaPelaIdade.getId() + " | " + pessoaPelaIdade.getNome() + " | " + pessoaPelaIdade.getIdade());
        }
    }

    public static Pessoa buscaPeloNome(ArrayList<Pessoa> pessoas, String nome) {

        for(Pessoa pessoa : pessoas) {
            if(pessoa.getNome().equals(nome)) {
                return pessoa;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static Pessoa buscaPelaIdade(ArrayList<Pessoa> pessoas, int idade) {

        for(Pessoa pessoa : pessoas) {
            if(pessoa.getIdade() == idade) {
                return pessoa;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

Saída:

> *Pessoa pelo nome: 2 | João | 25*
>   *Pessoa pela idade: 3 | Maria | 43*

Comment: Sua solução me ajudou bastante, muito obrigado.

Comment: @Ogarov legal. Ficou feliz por ter ajudado. Poderia marcar a resposta como solução, por favor? É o sinal de "check" debaixo do número de votos da resposta.

Comment: Você sabe como eu posso gerar um id para cada objeto que eu adicionar a ArrayList ? Tipo um ID que  não possa ser alterado e que seja pra sempre de um objeto ?

Comment: Existem várias formas de fazer isso, uma delas é criando um campo de `id` na classe em questão, receber esse id pelo construtor e fazer apenas o método _getter_ dele e não o setter. Vou editar a publicação para incluir isso. @Ogarov

Comment: @Ogarov resposta editada.

Answer (score 2):

A forma mais fácil é:

```
Arrays.asList("Débora", "Luan").stream().filter(string -> string.equals("Luan"))
    .collect(Collectors.reducing((a, b) -> null)).get();
```

Ou até, o que seria mais protegido em caso de não haver nenhum item que se assemelha à informação dada:

```
Arrays.asList("Débora", "Luan").stream().filter(parametroFiltro -> parametroFiltro.equals("Luan")).findFirst().get();
```

Eu usei algumas ferramentas disponiveis a partir da versão 1.8 do Java. Com as expressões lambda fica mais fácil escrever pequenas classes anonimas funcionais com apenas um método, que recebe um parâmetro (o parametroFiltro), e define ele dentro de um método (por isso utiliza-se a flecha, ->, para indicar como será sua execução).

Por exemplo, o método `filter` utilizado depois do `stream` é utilizado para "filtrar" a coleção a partir de uma dada verificação.

O código `.filter(parametroFiltro -> parametroFiltro.equals("valor")` pode ser substituído por:

```
.filter(new Predicate<String>(){

    @Override
    public boolean test(String parametroFiltro) {
        return parametroFiltro.equals("Luan");
    }
})
```

No caso do filter, como ele espera um objeto instanciado da interface Predicate, ele sabe que deve executar o código definido é `parametroFiltro -> parametroFiltro.equals("valor")` como um método que tem algo como retorno e recebe somente um parâmetro tipo String.

O segundo uso de lambda foi utilizado para definir como parâmetro de `reducing` uma instancia da classe BinaryOperator, que tem o método `apply` como um método que recebe duas variáveis e retorna um tipo T, definido na criação da classe anonima. nesse caso:

```
Collectors.reducing(new BinaryOperator<String>() {

    @Override
    public String apply(String a, String b) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Não se cobre quanto a isso, eu falei por que achei bacana dividir formas mais divertidas de tratar o assunto.

E de todas as formas, por favor, se pessoas mais estudadas no assunto conseguirem completar as informações fico imensamente grato.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, ainda sou iniciantes e tem umas coisas no seu código  que não entendo.

Comment: @Ogarov, Oook, pelo que você não entende suponho que sejam as expressões lambdas. Vou explicar da minha melhor forma. Fica aberto para outros melhorarem a explicação.

Answer (score 0):

tu cria uma classe que implementa um ArrayList e então tu pode implementar um método de busca e sobrescrevê-lo para cada atributo desejado. As coleções já implementam esses métodos padrões.
sort: Classifica os elementos de uma List.
binarySearch: Localiza um objeto em uma List usando o algoritmo de pesquisa binária de alto desempenho introduzido.
Para utilizá-los os objetos que tu colocar no ArrayList precisam ter o método
compareTo que é declarado na interface Comparable e, às vezes, é chamado método natural de comparação. A chamada sort pode especificar como um segundo argumento um objeto Comparator, que determina uma ordem alternativa dos elementos.
Referência é o Java - Como Programar 10ª ed.