# Qual a melhor forma de ordenação listas em Java?

Tags: java

Tenho uma lista, como exemplo:
Quero saber qual a melhor forma de ordenar essa lista por nome e idade respectivamente.

```
public class Pessoa{
    private String nome;
    private int idade;

    // gets e sets omitidos
}

public class PessoaNeg{
    private List<Pessoa> listaPessoas = new ArrayList<Pessoa>();

    public void adicionarPessoas(){
       Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();
       pessoa.setNome("João");
       pessoa.setIdade(10); 

       Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();
       pessoa.setNome("Filomena");
       pessoa.setIdade(11); 

       listaPessoas.add(pessoa);
    }

}
```

Comment: Ainda hoje passou uma pergunta exatamente igual à que está a fazer. Ora [veja a pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/252744/como-criar-um-m%C3%A9todo-de-pesquisa-por-elementos-em-uma-arraylist). A resposta usa até uma classe `Pessoa` como tem na sua pergunta

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como criar um método de pesquisa por elementos em uma ArrayList?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/252744/como-criar-um-m%c3%a9todo-de-pesquisa-por-elementos-em-uma-arraylist)

Comment: Na outra pergunta o problema era buscar, neste caso é ordenar. Acho que não é duplicata (pelo menos não da sinalizada).

Comment: Sim de facto tem alguma diferença no sentido que é ordenar especificamente e não buscar

Answer (score 6):

Ok, a **melhor** *melhor* forma vai depender de muitos fatores, inclusive da conjunção da projeção astral do Sol em relação a Vênus e onde sua sombra se projeta na casa dos Signos Lunares...

Um jeito *adequado* de fazer essa ordenação é chamando o `Collections.sort`.

A [solução do @Isac](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/253064/64969) eu creio que seja bem desacoplada, mas tem uma situação em que, se o objeto for garantidamente comparável e ordenável de maneira absoluta, não se precisa implementar um `Comparator` anônimo/efêmero.

Neste caso, o objeto precisa implementar `Comparable`. Então, como estamos lidando com a classe `Pessoa` e se deseja compará-la consigo mesma, façamos isso:

```
public class Pessoa implements Comparable<Pessoa> {
    private String nome;
    private int idade;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Pessoa outra) {
        int nomeCmp = nome.compareTo(outra.nome);
        // deu empate quanto aos nomes, então vai para o desempate de idade
        if (nomeCmp == 0) {
            return idade - outra.idade;
        }
        return nomeCmp;
    }

    // gets e sets omitidos
}
```

Pronto, agora só precisa chamar alguém que saiba ordenar uma lista com comparáveis... E esse é o [`Collections.sort(List<T extends Comparable<? super T>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)).

Agora, basta chamar:

```
List<Pessoa> pessoas = new ArrayList<>();

// ... povoa a lista ...

Collections.sort(pessoas);
```

PS: eu usaria *normalmente* a solução do @Isac, normalmente não tenho em muitos casos essa **ordenação absoluta**.

Comment: Não dá para fazer o programa calcular qual é a conjunção da projeção astral do Sol em relação a Vênus e onde sua sombra se projeta na casa dos Signos Lunares e com essa informação, escolher a melhor implementação?

Comment: Talvez dê. Talvez você vá se encontrar no problema da parada, ou então a descoberta da ordenação ótima seja PSPACE ou mesmo R, eu particularmente  ao consigo determinar a classe de problema da ordenação ótima. Imagina, a lista que me vem é uma lista ligada? Ou um conjunto de arrays de tamanhos variáveis ligadas em apenas uma direção? Ou na verdade é uma árvore binária balanceada que se percorre em pré ordem? E a distribuição dos dados vai fazer o quicksort ser melhor do que o timsort? Ou devo usar um bucketsort com um heapsort dentro de cada bucket misturando tudo com shellsort depois?

Comment: Sem falar que "melhor pra quem"? E se quem for fazer a manutenção no sistema não entenda os cálculos de desvio fractal da entropia dos dados e fizer besteira? Devo fazer um código melhor para o computador processar ou para o humano entender? E para qual computador processar melhor? Se for custoso acessar memória externa, devo tentar fazer várias pequenas ordenações  nos poucos registradores disponíveis e depois juntar tudo?

Comment: Também tem o caso de que, talvez, seja mais barato computacionalmente falando ir para a heurística de executar sempre um shellsort do que calcular a projeção astral **e depois** ainda aplicar uma ordenação...

Answer (score 5):

Existem muitas formas de ordenar, sendo à mão ou utilizando já funções feitas. E existem vários tipos de algoritmos de ordenação. Cada um pode ser melhor ou pior dependendo do objetivo e tipo de dados que tem.

Irei mostrar uma utilizando lambdas e baseando-se no algoritmo interno do `sort` para `ArrayList`. Para ordenar apenas por `nome` pode fazer:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       List<Pessoa> listaPessoas = new ArrayList<>();

       listaPessoas.add(new Pessoa("João", 10));
       listaPessoas.add(new Pessoa("Filomena", 11));
       listaPessoas.add(new Pessoa("Martim", 25));
       listaPessoas.add(new Pessoa("Ana", 21));
       listaPessoas.add(new Pessoa("Rui", 9));  

       listaPessoas.sort((p1,p2)->p1.getNome().compareTo(p2.getNome())); //ordenação
       listaPessoas.forEach(x->System.out.println(x.obterInformacoes()));
    }
}
```

Saida:

```
Nome: Ana, Idade: 21
Nome: Filomena, Idade: 11
Nome: João, Idade: 10
Nome: Martim, Idade: 15
Nome: Rui, Idade: 9
```

Em que aqui vê que a ordenação das pessoas se baseia na comparação dos seus nomes, uma vez que é chamado o `compareTo` do nome de `p1`, a primeira pessoa, para `p2`.

[Veja este exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/GU6lP8)

Se quiser ordenar por nome e para cada nome igual ordenar por idade já tem que elaborar um pouco no método de ordenação:

```
listaPessoas.sort((p1,p2)-> {
    int compNomes = p1.getNome().compareTo(p2.getNome());
    return compNomes == 0 ? p1.getIdade()-p2.getIdade():compNomes;
});
```

Note que o `compareTo` devolve `0` quando ambas as `Strings` são iguais.

[Veja também este exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/bpZfki)

Documentação:

- [`sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator))
- [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String))

Comment: Use a sintaxe do diamante e troque `ArrayList<Pessoa>` por `ArrayList<>`. Só não recomendo deixar isso como estático porque não é lá uma das melhores práticas de programação usar o `static` para isso (use como variável local mesmo).

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário. A sintaxe do diamante costumo fazer sempre como indicou, mas neste casou passou mesmo.  Quanto ao estático, foi mesmo para tentar manter a mesma estrutura, ainda que na classe que tem o `main`, mas concordo que não é grande pratica, e por isso alterei também.